# Format date time in cts:element-values

Tags: xquery, marklogic, cts, marklogic-8

I want to format dateTime with in the cts:element-values itself. Can anyone help me around this?

I have a dateTime format string -

```
let $date-format := "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[h01]:[m01]:[s01].[f1]"
```

and I want to use it in a query like this -

```
cts:element-values(
  xs:QName($field),
  (), 
  ($direction), 
  cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("urn:iddn:collections:searchable"), cts:query($cts-query)))
  )
```

Provided $field is of type dateTime.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pretty-print the output of cts:element-values? Or do you mean you want to adjust content on read for the benefit of the index?

Comment: The data is in the form of date time and I want to get only month and year values for rest I need 0.
Example - if I have dateTime = 2015-10-12T22:32:11,
I want to get either 2015-10 or 2015-10-01T00:00:00

Comment: cts:element-values( ... ) !  fn:format-dateTime( . , "[Y0001]-[M01]" )

Comment: @DALDEI You should write that up as a full answer; so it's more visible (and you get rep). Might be worth using the full `for` syntax, since ML *still* defaults to xquery-1.

Comment: @DALDEI - I  don't want to have an extra loop in place for formatting date.  Is there any option by which I can get formatted date as result of cts:element-values(....)

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj cts:element-values returns the indexed values of that element; if you want some other value, you'll have to do some processing, either after the call to css:element-values, or before you insert the data into the DB.

Comment: You might also want to get the distinct-values, which is not possible directly from the lexicon either. I would also be interested to learn a little more about what this is for. Some kind of facet perhaps? If so you could perhaps leverage search constraint buckets.

Comment: Yes it is for facets only. I want to get facets aggregated on date. But I cann't use buckets because the limits are dynamic and can be even for days and months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by writing a User-Defined Function. UDFs are run as map/reduce, so they are very fast even with a large data set. I wrote an [example UDF to create a day-of-the-week facet](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2012/09/a-mapreduce-aggregation-function-in-marklogic-6/) based on dateTime data. That example is based on MarkLogic 6, but should still work in MarkLogic 8.

The good thing is that UDFs are very fast. The tricky part is that you'll have to write it in C++. Full documentation in the [User-Defined Functions section](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/aggregateUDFs#chapter) of the MarkLogic documentation.